# Taylor/Maclaurin Series Exam Question.

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Show that if x is small compared with unity, then $$f(x)=\frac{(1-x)^\frac{-2}{3}+(1-4x)^\frac{-1}{3}}{(1-3x)^\frac{-1}{3}+(1-4x)^\frac{-1}{4}}=1-\frac{7x^2}{36}.$$

I've expanded all the brackets of f(x) up to the 2nd order and I'v ended up with $$f(x)=\frac{2+2x+\frac{37x^2}{9}}{2+2x+\frac{9x^2}{2}}$$ I can't seem to be able to simplify this to get $1-\frac{7x^2}{36}$. Can someone tell me what to do from here? I'm certain that the question does not require me to find $f'(o)$ and $f''(o)$ as this would be to time-consuming and this is an exam question.

Thank you.

Comment: Removing the revision tag per discussion here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/whats-up-with-the-revision-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert $(37/9)x^2$ to $(74/18)x^2$ and $(9/2)x^2$ to $(81/18)x^2$. Using this you can get:

$$ f(x) = \frac{2 + 2x + \frac{81x^2}{18} - \frac{7x^2}{18}}{2 + 2x + \frac{81x^2}{18}}$$

This simplifies to

$$ f(x) = 1 - \frac{\frac{7x^2}{18}}{2 + 2x + \frac{81x^2}{18}}$$

For small $x$ or $x$ close to zero, you can simplify the denominator to $2$ because $2x + \frac{81x^2}{18} \approx 0 $. This gives you

$$f(x) = 1 - \frac{7x^2}{36}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$1/(1 + x +(9/4) x^2) = 1 -(x + (9/4) x^2) + (x + (9/4) x^2)^2 + 
\ldots $$